# portsentry and IPTables on constant reboot, but not sure why

Tags: centos, security, iptables

I have been doing some hardening on a new server [ centos 5.7 final ]
i also have logwatch and seem to be getting these strange logs

```
Commands Run:
User root:
   /sbin/service portsentry restart >/dev/null && /sbin/service iptables restart >/dev/null: 72 Time(s)
```

Then the portsentry log is:

```
--------------------- PortSentry Begin ------------------------ 


 Ignored following ports
Advanced Stealth:
   TCP: ports: 21-22 25 53 80 110-111 113 135 137-139 443 932

Excluded following ports
Advanced: ports: 21-22 25 53 80 110 113 135 137-139 443

**Unmached entries**
72 Time(s): adminalert: Advanced mode will monitor first 1024 ports
72 Time(s): adminalert: ERROR: Socket 111 is in use and will not be monitored. Attempting to continue
72 Time(s): adminalert: Going into stealth listen mode on UDP port: 1
72 Time(s): adminalert: Going into stealth listen mode on UDP port: 111
72 Time(s): adminalert: Going into stealth listen mode on UDP port: 137
72 Time(s): adminalert: Going into stealth listen mode on UDP port: 138
etc etc ......   then
144 Time(s): adminalert: PortSentry 1.2 is starting.
144 Time(s): adminalert: PortSentry is shutting down
144 Time(s): securityalert: PortSentry is shutting down

 ---------------------- PortSentry End -------------------------
```

I am a little puzzled to say the least, if i log on and start portsentry manually i get an okay for the close and an okay for the start, so i can get it to run, just cant seem to stop it from starting and stopping after that.

I have looked in crontab and there is no repeating entry for the first section [ commands run]  this log is from cron.

If anyone else has come accross this, or can give me a clue then that would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

111 is most propably the portmap daemon. Why is that beast running on your server at all?

If you need it because of the need for an NFS-client use

```
PMAP_ARGS="-l"
```

In /etc/sysconfig/portmap

That will bind it to localhost.

Comment: that's not an answer to the question but thankks for the advice